# Improve Database Table Design

Tags: python, database, postgresql, database-design, query-optimization

I’m trying to design a database table, which will be updated by service A. And on the other side, there will be service B that will read the data by filtering some rows.

Here is the example of the current table:

| reference_id | rent_id | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 | 2021-10-14 |
| 2 | 25 | 64 | 2021-10-13 |
| 3 | 125 | 512 | 2021-10-14 |
| 4 | 5 | 64 | 2021-10-14 |

By the way, here is the table creation:

```
create table MyTable
(
    reference_id integer,
    rent_id integer,
    price integer,
    date date not null,
    constraint uniq_reference_id_rent_id_date
        unique (reference_id, rent_id, date)
);

create index ix_MyTable_date
    on MyTable (date);
```

And the data in service B is like:

```
 {date_1: [(reference_id_1, rent_id_1), (reference_id_2, rent_id_2), ...]}
```

So there are one contraint and one problem related to performance.

- Data in service B can not be modified.
- SQL query to get the results is not performant. Let me explain:

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE date = date_1 AND
         (reference_id = reference_id_1 AND rent_id = rent_id_1) OR
         (reference_id = reference_id_2 AND rent_id = rent_id_2) OR
         (reference_id = reference_id_3 AND rent_id = rent_id_3) OR
         ...
```

This query is not performant at all on PostgreSQL 10.14. And we also know the row we are looking for the couple (reference_id_1, rent_id_1) **may not exist**.

So I am looking for different solutions to redesign my table. One solution is to create an additional column that contains **the hash value of (reference_id_1, rent_id_1) couple**.

Finally, I believe your ideas will allow me to improve this solution proposed by my co-workers or find out another solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you correctly used indexes to resolve the performance problem?

Comment: Two columns (reference_id_1, rent_id_1) are already indexed.

Comment: Try to put an index on date too. Use explain too see how Postgres will works. Evaluate the use of multi column index for reference and rent. Try to think if an hash index on date can be the right choice

Comment: To help you with [tag:query-optimization] questions, we usually need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The question has been edited with create table example. [O.jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones)

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is fine. You need a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-multicolumn.html) to help you satisfy this query.  There's no need to use a hash value column for this.

I suggest this one.

```
 CREATE INDEX ref_rent_date
     ON TABLE MyTable
  USING BTREE (reference_id, rent_id, date);
```

I suggest putting your `date` column last in the index, so you can use it to search on date ranges (`WHERE date >= '2021-01-01'`) as well as specific dates in the query pattern you showed us.

**Pro tip**: Don't create lots of single column indexes unless you know your query patterns will need them, or you know you need them for UNIQUE constraints and the like. Most queries with multiple items in their WHERE clauses do better with multicolumn indexes created to match the query pattern.

**Pro tip 2** As applications and their tables grow, it's often necessary to add new indexes to match the actual query patterns. SQL is designed so indexes can be added and removed without affecting the data.

Read https://use-the-index-luke.com by Marcus Winand.